# How do you delete a PFObject in iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I don't quite understand how the whereKey, equalTo works.

- I've read the documentation at **[Parse.com](http://parse.com)** and other related questions but don't quite seem to understand how to relate and find the object you are looking for.
- What I am trying to do is to delete a `PFObject` (an image) after a person has disliked it. With this following code I get the `Error` of no results matched the query.

Could someone please explain to me how the linking of this works?

**EDITED CODE (NOW FUNCTIONING CORRECTLY):**

```
- (IBAction)likeLook:(id)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile.image, 1);
        [self deleteImage:imageData];

    } 
    else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Liked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageFile.image, 1);
        [self uploadImage:imageData];

        NSLog(@"Liked Image");

    }
}

-(void)deleteImage:(NSData *)imageData {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserLikedPhoto"];

[query whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"likedImage"];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object) {
        NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved the object.");
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded && !error) {
                NSLog(@"Image deleted from Parse");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
}];


}
-(void)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData {

    PFFile *likedImage = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];

    [likedImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            PFObject *userLikedPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserLikedPhoto"];
            [userLikedPhoto setObject:likedImage forKey:@"likedLook"];

            userLikedPhoto.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [userLikedPhoto setObject:user forKey:@"User"];

            [userLikedPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saved");

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@%@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@%@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Are you using "likedLook" as a placeholder for the objectId or is that your actual code?  If that's your actual code then that's most likely the issues.  The objectId is the parse object ID (you can find it in the data browser to see what I'm talking about).

Comment: likedLook is the column where the images are saved. If you see the method uploadImage that is where the image first saves in the Data Browser when the image is liked. Thats why I don't quite understand how to find the object. Could you help with some code please? Or maybe an explanation of how the whereKey, equalTo works please?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your flow, Adrienne. Why are you uploading and storing an image if a user likes it, and then removing it if a user dislikes it? I have a feeling there is a design flaw here that should be sorted out, but I can't be sure until I know what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Handsomeguy When a user likes the image, the image is then downloaded in another view (favorites view) in a UICollectionView through a query.. but if the user dislikes the image I want the image to be deleted in this 'favorites view'

Comment: So, "dislike" in this context actually means "I don't want it in my favorites view anymore"? Because I can't see why a user would dislike an image that she previously liked...

Comment: @Handsomeguy exactly, I have to give the option to the user to not want it in their favorites view anymore.

Comment: Ok, so it is just the UserLikedPhoto object that should be deleted. Then I think the solution provided by @CEarwood should work since you don't want to delete the actual photo from Parse.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to change `deleteImage:` to accept the objectId rather than NSData.  You can't query parse for a matching data blog (I'm pretty sure anyway, either way it's bad practice).

```
-(void)deleteImage:(NSString *)objectId {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserLikedPhoto"];

[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object) {
        NSLog(@"The getFirstObject request failed.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved the object.");
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded && !error) {
                NSLog(@"Image deleted from Parse");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
}];
}
```

In this case you don't even need the whereKey filter on the query because we're looking for a specific object. You can store the objectId in the saveInBackgroundWithBlock success block under upload image. I hope that helps.

**EDIT**

From the Parse PFFile Documentation:

> You can delete files that are referenced by objects using the REST
>   API. You will need to provide the master key in order to be allowed to
>   delete a file.
>
> If your files are not referenced by any object in your app, it is not
>   possible to delete them through the REST API. You may request a
>   cleanup of unused files in your app's Settings page. Keep in mind that
>   doing so may break functionality which depended on accessing
>   unreferenced files through their URL property. Files that are
>   currently associated with an object will not be affected.

I've never used Parse files but this does seem pretty odd to me.  You must use the Master Key to delete files so I would not recommend doing it in your iOS app.   You can create a Cloud Code function that handles the delete for you if you'd like or you can just delete the UserLikedPhoto object and periodically request file cleanup.

Comment: This will delete the UserLikedPhoto object, but not the associated PFFile for the image

Comment: It's throwing an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: NSConcreteMutableData'.

Comment: I added a previous code in my question that I was using that doesn't give any error but doesn't delete the Object either.

Comment: Based on your last edit I think the best thing for you to do is read the Parse documentation thoroughly.  It sounds like you just don't understand how PFObject works i.e. objectForKey: is basically a getter so calling it just returns a value to nothing since you're not setting a variable.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is this line: [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:@"likedLook"];  When you store the image in favorites, also keep track of the objectId of the UserLikedPhoto. When you call delete, provide that objectId to the function and get the UserLikedPhoto object like suggested in this answer.

Comment: @Handsomeguy what I don't really understand is how the whereKey works as stated in my question. I found the solution. Even though I really don't understand how it is working but it does delete the object. No need for cloud code. SEE EDIT.

Comment: I don't see how that code can work correctly as you in the query are asking for the first object it finds that DOES NOT HAVE a photo file linked to it. This probably only works because that is your last saved object. I believe it will break if you have several. I will update @CEarwood's answer with how your flow should be.

Comment: @adriennemhenry whereKey works by searching for an object WHERE a KEY is EQUALTO whatever you pass in.  You really need to read the Parse documentation. It's fantastic and actually explains how it works. Per the pars documentation "use the whereKey:equalTo: method to constrain the value for a key." That's as concise a description as you could ask for.